# Backbone.js - View in Collection adding item to another (sibling) Collection

Tags: backbone.js

In my example I have a parent model (`ModelParent`) with two collections (A and B), which hold `ModelA`'s and `ModelB`'s respectively.  There are associated views for each model (`ViewParent`, `ViewA`, and `ViewB`)

**I would like a function in `ViewA` to add a new item to `CollectionB`.**

**What's the best way to do this? (couple of possibilities below):**

- Should `ViewA` be passed a reference to `ViewParent`, when it is created? How best to do this? (as far as I know there is now in build parent reference)
- Should `ViewParent` be stored in the `window` scope, so that `ViewA` can refrence it like `window.ViewA`? (This seems wrong to me)

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative than listening directly to events from your collection, is the use of an **eventBus**. Derick Bailey from Los techies wrote a nice [article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/) where he introduces the idea of communication between different components (in his case views) via an eventBus.

If you are firm with *coffeescript* - and possibly even if you're not - you should also check this nice [extension](http://thurloat.com/2012/01/21/backbonejs-readable-modular-testable-views) from Adam Thurlow.

Side note: If your situation simply requires communication between the two elements an eventBus is most likely overkill, although the idea is imho ultra simple. Apart from that, I am of the believe, that a central component for communication is worth the effort as it simplifies messaging, supports decoupling and gives your architecture a reliable consistency.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider thinking about it a different way.  I believe it would be cleaner if you didn't have to pass references all around your views.  Instead, use backbone's built in event model and keep the "add new item to CollectionB" logic inside ViewParent.  When ViewParent instantiates ViewA, you could immediately bind to an event on it:

```
this.viewA = new ViewA({});
this.viewA.bind("some_event_that_requires_adding_to_collection", this.onViewAEvent);
```

Inside ViewA, whenever you want to add to CollectionB, just trigger the event:

```
this.trigger("some_event_that_requires_adding_to_collection", itemIWantToAdd);
```

Add additional arguments to the trigger call to pass them to any callback bound to the event.

Comment: Both answers mention a Mediator pattern, which is great! For a background reading check out: http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/.